# Очищение консоли в Python3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, консоль

Пытался сделать элементарную программу, которая очищает всю консоль. Есть код:

```py
for i in range(1, 10):
    print(i)
```

требуется после этой программы стереть все, что написала функция

```py
print(i)
```

Помогите пожалуйста!!! Перепробовал все способы, которые писали, ни один не помогает!!!
Если что то у меня MacOS

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20247284/6571020

Comment: Не работает. Пишет:  TERM environment variable not set.

Comment: проверил - Command+K работает в  Терминал на Mac OS X, чтобы очистить экран.

Comment: вот вроде ваша проблема - вернее решение PyCharm – TERM environment variable not set - https://softwaretester.info/pycharm-term-environment-variable-not-set/

Comment: У меня не PyChram (Все у меня не то)

Comment: CTRL + L ? Такой вариант не подходит? нужно сделать средствами языка?

Comment: да, именно так.

Answer (score 1):

Вызовите команду clear через модуль os(или subprocess):

```
import os
os.system("clear")
```